# Error: Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag' while rendering ValueBox

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr, shinydashboard

I have two R files in my shiny dashboard app. `global.R` and `app.R`.

Under `global.R` I have the following structure.

```
ShedArea <- c("Shed 1", "Shed 2", "Shed 3","Shed 4")
SeedsReceived_KGS <- c(14,24,8,19)
DF <- data.frame(ShedArea,SeedsReceived_KGS,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
shed_area <- unique(DF$ShedArea)
mean_seeds <- mean(DF$SeedsReceived_KGS)
```

In `app.R`, I've implemented a `pickerInput` where one can select a single or all sheds, and a `valueBoxOutput` to display the mean of the selected shed or of all sheds.

Contents of `app.R`.

UI

```
source("global.R")
valueBoxOutput("av_seeds_received")
pickerInput(inputId = "shed", label = "Select Shed", choices = shed_area, selected = shed_area, options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE),multiple = TRUE)
```

Server

```
output$av_seeds_received <- renderValueBox({
filter(DF, ShedArea==input$shed) %>%
valueBox("Seeds Received", round(mean_seeds, digits=2))
})
```

When I `runApp()`, I get an `Error: Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'.`

How do I go about resolving this, so that when the a shed is selected, the mean value of seeds received is displayed?

Comment: First of all you need `filter(DF, ShedArea %in% input$shed)`. See if this fixes the error. Also you need to calculate `mean_seeds` inside `renderValueBox`.

Comment: @Shree, I've made the adjustments and the value is appearing. mean of all sheds. However, when you select one shed, the mean value doesn't change. The filter isn't implementing. Might you know what could be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you probably need -

```
output$av_seeds_received <- renderValueBox({
  df <- filter(DF, ShedArea %in% input$shed)
  mean_seeds <- mean(df$SeedsReceived_KGS, na.rm = T) %>% round(2)
  valueBox(mean_seeds, "Seeds Received")
})
```

Comment: Why is this issue cropping up for so many people: Because no one expects to use `valueBox()` inside the `renderValueBox()` function on  the server side.

Answer (score 8):

This may not solve OP's exact issue but I also got this cryptic error when I had `icon = ("keyboard")` in my tab code (instead of `icon = icon("keyboard")`)

Just leaving this here in case other people making this mistake get to this question from google like I did.